# How to retrieve last modified timestamp from postgres table and pass that to a condition using pyspark

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark-sql, timestamp, pyspark

I have a postgres table "log", which has a column called "timestamp" which has the date and time of files in a folder.

I need to retrieve the latest timestamp from table and pass this in a "for condition" but **initially the table will be empty**, from second iteration i need to fetch from the table **using pyspark**

Please let me know how to go about it

so far i tried

```
       log_qry = """select timestamp from log order by timestamp desc limit 1"""
       cursor.execute = log_qry
       conn.commit
```

this seems to be not working

Comment: your query is wrong. it should be `select timestamp from log order by timestamp desc limit 1`

Comment: yes sorry while typing i missed it, but still it is not working

Comment: remove where from the query and give a try

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like below:

```
select timestamp from log order by timestamp desc limit 1
```

it will return 0 records if there is no record in your table `log`.

better you try it with `max` like below:

```
select max(timestamp) from log
```

it will return 1 record always, if table is empty then it will return `null` else it will return the max `timestamp` from the column `timestamp`.

**Don't use reserve keywords and column name**

Comment: okay thanks i will try it out. But how do i use this value obtained in my "for condition "in pyspark

Comment: you should ask separate question for that with full code. this answer will resolve only SQL related problem

Answer (score 0):

`timestamp` is a reserved word and should be double-quoted if used as a name in a query.
If null is not acceptable for your "for condition" then coalesce it to a date/time very very long ago.

```sql
select coalesce(max("timestamp"), '0001-01-01T00:00:00'::timestamp) from "log";
```